# OnMarkerViewAddedListener not called after add MarkerView successful

Tags: android, mapbox

I add MarkView to the map like

```
mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
             @Override
             public void onMapReady(final MapboxMap mapboxMap) {

             mapboxMap.animateCamera(
                        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(35.50, 139.125), 6));

             mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerViewOptions().position(new LatLng(35.75, 139.125)), new MarkerViewManager.OnMarkerViewAddedListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onViewAdded(@NonNull MarkerView markerView) {
                     Log.i("TAG", "onViewAdded");
                     Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     // this never called
                 }
             });
         }
```

It already displayed in the map but onViewAdded not called.

my dependencies

```
compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.0.2@aar') {
   transitive = true
}
```

Why OnMarkerViewAddedListener not call and how to make it work? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.